# Access properties of object

Tags: properties, php-5.3

I have an object that looks like this in PHP 5  when returned from var_dump($result);  :

```
object(stdClass)#4 (1) {
  ["pong"]=>
  object(stdClass)#5 (1) {
    ["message"]=>
    string(9) "It works!"
  }
}
```

How do I access ["Message"]?

Sorry ... I'm very new to php 5.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is:

```
$result->pong->message
```